# unique value based in a different columns data

Tags: excel, unique

Okay so here’s what I need….   And let me preface this by saying I know this can be done in a pivot table however, I am trying to avoid using a pivot table.

```
Col J       Col M     Col Q
origdest    weeknum   Wks Shipped - Prior 12 Months
AAABBBCCC   48        3
XXXX        44        2
AAABBBCCC   48        3 
XXXX        44        2
AAABBBCCC   44        3
XXXX        45        2
YYYY        48        1
AAABBBCCC    3        3
ZZZZZ       48        1
```

In column Q, I need a formula that will give me the unique value in column M of the matching column J (which should give me the result shown in column Q..  In other words, I need to know how many weeks that “origdest” shipped.  It seems like it should be pretty simple but I can’t seem to make anything work and I have had an issue with entering an array formula, it hangs up my computer.

Comment: Your first step is to [repair your Office installation](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) so that it doesn't hang when entering an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly [standard method of achieving unique counts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2003-excel/count-unique-with-sumproduct-breakdown/1bc18979-4172-4537-993e-3897f74d6a5b) involving the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) and the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34). Your situation demands that more criteria be introduced by substituting COUNTIF for the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

In Q2 try this standard formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((J$2:J$99=J2)*(J$2:J$99<>""))/COUNTIFS(J$2:J$99, J$2:J$99&"", M$2:M$99, M$2:M$99&""))
```

Fill down as necessary. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Unique count with SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS]

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried something similar but couldn't get it quite right...this worked like a charm!